# What are uncles?

Tags: historical, terminology, authorship

Coming across a few pallets like Authorship, one finds a frequent mention of `Uncles` or `UncleGenerations`. What are uncles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each block, besides the genesis has a parent block. Let's assume you are building block X, the parent is X - 1. This means that all forks (blocks on with the same block number as X - 1) of X - 1 are the uncles of X.

Comment: Are forks from X - 2 uncles of X as well?

Comment: AB
    / 
A1    B1     C1
|        |         |
A --> B --> C --> D
|
A2

The uncles of D, with a maximum "generation" of `3` would be `C1, B1, A1, A2`.